# Ubuntu 18.04 lagging workspaces

Tags: windows, 18.04, workspaces

Since the upgrade to 18.04 I noticed an annoying lag when switching between workspaces and while opening/closing windows. I have an xps with i7 8th gen and 16gb of ram so computer is not the problem and the installation is quite fresh. Can it be caused by the upgrade from a 17.10 ubuntu version and not  a new installation? Do you guys think that things will be solved with the release of 18.04.1?

Answer (score 1):

On Login screen: click on settings(gear) icon and choose "Gonme on XOrg". Not the default "Gnome".

I also disabled "animations" using "Tweaks" tool.

Comment: Ok I will give it a try!